# How to config startup script for jupyterhub?

Tags: python, jupyterhub

I have set up a jupyterhub python notebook server on ubuntu. I want to add some startup scripts so that when an user is logged into notebook server, some packages and modules will be automatically loaded. Is there any configure file where I can specify startup scripts? Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this in the config options

```
# lines of code to run at IPython startup.
# c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = []
```

It allows you to run specific commands on startup. You can also put in scripts in ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup, but depending on your spawner these can require a bit of setup to make sure they get loaded.

Comment: are you able to expand on the second option?